# How to undo a delete tags folder action from svn repo browser

Tags: svn, tags, tortoisesvn, undo

Unfortunately I deleted my entire tags folder from svn repo browser. Can I undo that? If there is any solution to retrieve data please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using TortoiseSVN only you cannot undo the delete operation, but you can copy the `tags` folder from older revision to your `HEAD` revision. Here is how you do it:

1. Open your repo-browser.
2. Click on the button labeled `HEAD` (right top corner).
3. Enter there the revision number just before deletion of `tags`.
4. Right-click on`tags` folder in repo-browser.
5. Select Copy to...
6. In the appeared dialog box input the desired path to `tags` (http://domain/svn/repo/tags).
7. Open a new repo-browser window and ensure that `tags` are there.

If you haven't committed anything since `tags` deletion, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668843/deleting-recent-commits-in-svn) answer to completely remove unwanted revisions (requires access to svn server and usage of `svnadmin` commands).

Comment: Your soultion seems valid but I just want to point out that you *can* undo the delete operation with TortoiseSVN: you just have to check out a working copy for the repo root, e.g. `http://example.com/myrepo` instead of `http://example.com/myrepo/trunk`

Comment: That's true, but if you have a lot of tags, you probably won't want to check out the entire repository.